Adding custom claims to access token and Id token in Authlib
I am using Authlib for implementing OIDC server. I want to add the sid claim in the access token and id token. This sid claim is used for session identifier in the case of logout. As per RP initiated logout spec, we are using sid for clearing sessions.
Also I was not able to find documentation on adding custom claims.
To my knowledge, the default token generators are not giving any provision for adding custom claims whose values need to be derived from request or session context.
#authlib.oauth2.rfc6749.authorization_server
class AuthorizationServer:
    def generate_token(self, grant_type, client, user=None, scope=None,
                       expires_in=None, include_refresh_token=True):
        ...
        return func(
            grant_type=grant_type, client=client, user=user, scope=scope,
            expires_in=expires_in, include_refresh_token=include_refresh_token)

Is there any anyway to access to the Authorization Code object and Oauth request object without me overriding AuthorizationCodeGrant's base class BaseGrant generate_token method.
Looking for suggestions and documentation links if any related to this.
